# Avoiding duplicates in my result table

Tags: sql, t-sql, match

Currently I have this table (#tmp) in my TSQL query:

```
| a  |  b |
|:---|---:|
| 1  | 2  |
| 1  | 3  |
| 4  | 5  |
| 6  | 7  |
| 9  | 7  |
| 4  | 0  |
```

This table contains IDs of rows that I want to delete from another table. The thing is, I cannot have the same 'a' matching up with multiple 'b' and vice-versa, a single 'b' cannot match up with multiple 'a'. So essentially I need to remove the (1,3), (9,7), and (4,0) because either their 'a' or 'b' has already been used. I'm using the code below to try and do this but it seems like if a given 'a' has multiple corresponding 'b' that are higher AND lower than 'a' it causes an issue.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #tmp

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#KeysToDelete') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #KeysToDelete

CREATE TABLE #tmp (a int, b int)

INSERT INTO #tmp (a, b)
VALUES (1,2), (1,3),(4,5),(6,7), (9,7), (4,0)

SELECT * FROM #tmp

-- Get the minimum b for each a
select distinct
  a,
  (SELECT MIN(b) FROM #tmp t2 WHERE t2.a = t1.a) AS b
INTO #KeysToDelete
FROM #tmp t1
WHERE t1.a < t1.b

-- Get the minimum a for each b
INSERT INTO #KeysToDelete
select distinct
  (SELECT MIN(a) FROM #tmp t2 WHERE t2.a = t1.a) AS a,
  b
FROM #tmp t1
WHERE t1.a > t1.b

SELECT DISTINCT a, b 
FROM #KeysToDelete
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

The output is this:

```
| a  |  b |
|:---|---:|
| 1  | 2  |
| 4  | 0  |
| 6  | 7  |
| 9  | 7  |
```

But I really want this:

```
| a  |  b |
|:---|---:|
| 1  | 2  |  -- it would match requirements if this were (1,3) instead
| 4  | 5  |  -- it would match requirements if this were (4,0) instead
| 6  | 7  |  -- it would match requirements if this were (9,7) instead
```

If anyone has any idea how I might be able to fix this it would be much appreciated! I know this is a long involved questions, but any suggestions you may have would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Select * from #tmp t
Where Not exists(select * from #tmp 
                 where b = t.b 
                    and a < t.a)
  and Not exists(select * from #tmp 
                 where a = t.a 
                    and b < t.b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem statement is not well-defined.  There are multiple ways that you could remove rows from the `@tmp`, enforcing the uniqueness of columns A and B.

Here is one approach, which is to make A unique and then make B unique:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by a order by newid()) as a_seqnum
      from #tmp t
     )
delete from todelete
    where a_seqnum > 1;

with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by b order by newid()) as b_seqnum
      from #tmp t
     )
delete from todelete
    where b_seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: This works! I'm not familiar with a lot of the functions you used however, I think I may go with the solution provided by Charles below because that seems to work as well and it seems a bit more simple.

Answer (score 0):

i think I like the **Gordon's** solution better
I did a similar thing, but without the deleting parts:

```
;WITH CTE1 ( a , b )
AS
(
select a , b from
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY a ) AS Row , a , b
      from #tmp ) t
      where [row] = 1 
),
CTE2 (a, b)
AS
(
select a , b from
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b ORDER BY a ) AS Row , a , b
      from #tmp ) t
      where [row] = 1 
)

select * from CTE2
```